# Python - How to perform a reading of data sent via POST correctly?

Tags: python, post, csrf, sys

I come from PHP and there I used something like this to get the JSON that was sent to me via POST:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);

$sellerCode = $obj->{'sellerCode'};
$timezone = $obj->{'timezone'};
```

Now I am trying to do something similar in Python ...

```
json_data = sys.stdin.read()
obj = json.loads(json_data)

sellerCode = obj['sellerCode']
timezone = obj['timezone']
```

I have done some tests through Postman sending the relevant JSON, but I get a 403.
I've already been doing some research on the 403 and the most common solution I find is related to import:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
```

and then the label before the function that will receive the json, getting something like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json
import os, sys
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def enviar(request):
    json_data = sys.stdin.read()
    return HttpResponse('Ok')
```

The result?
Postman no longer shows the 403, but now simply waits for an answer, which never comes.

So now I don't know which way to go.
I am convinced that I have a problem with that 'sys.stdin'. I mean, it's a very simple program and I'm just testing it with localhost. IDK

Or do I really already have to face problems with permissions and security terms to use the '@csrf_exempt'?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You can use ˋ request.data[keyname] ˋ to search for given body params, when using the django rest framework package.

Comment: That's right, I think the solution is to use Django Rest and something called "ORM", I am currently investigating it.
I will wait a day before closing the question, in case someone else wants to suggest something to me.
Thank you.

Comment: I could give you an example as answer, if this helps you.